# Highlight Selected text with different color for each tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, text, highlight

Text Selection and highlighting is not working when I want to select the text on clicking of a dynamic button, but it works when I directly select the text from paragraph (on `mouseup`) itself. (see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqhpfcwv/4/) for complete code)

I have generated dynamic buttons for each tag with various color, eg. `Tag1`-Green, `Tag2`-Blue, `Tag3`-Red,...etc

So when user clicks on :

- `Tag1` button, selected text from the paragraph should get highlighted in the `green` color
- `Tag2` button, selected text from the paragraph should get highlighted in the `blue` color
- `Tag3` button, selected text from the paragraph should get highlighted in the `red` color
  ...etc

  ```
  var getSelectedText = function() {
  var selectedRange ="";
  try {
      if (window.getSelection) {
          selectedRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      } else {
          selectedRange = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      }
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
  }
  return selectedRange
  };

   function highlight(){
     //Below Commented code works fine
    // $("p.raw_text").on("mouseup", function(e) {
    //   e.preventDefault()
    //   var selection = getSelectedText(); 
    //    alert("Selection: " + selection);
    // }); 

   //But this code does not work as buttons with id that starts with highlight are dynamically generated
    $(document).on('click', '[id^=highlight]', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      var selection = getSelectedText(); 
       alert("Selection: " + selection);
    }); 
   }

   $(function(){
     highlight();  
   });
  ```

**P.S** Highlighting of the text is not yet implemented as I am not getting the selected text to highlight it..

**EDIT**

**Note** - I am trying to build a data annotation tool to annotate my machine learning training data. What it does is, it allows users to select the [NER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition) text to be annotated and mark it with specific label(or tag). Ex. selected text could be a person's name from the paragraph, then user should click on the Tag (Person) and highlight the selected text from the paragraph with some color, similarly there could be any number of Tags(labels) in the paragraph such as organization, city, country, etc User should be able to highlight each NER with specific color. (which further, I will pass that resultant data along with its highlighted indexes to build a machine learning model.)

Comment: I have read your question looked at the sample, but I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Perhaps you could give an example of the behavior you want, based off the sample you have so far.

Comment: @DavidTran - Please take a look, modified the question. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Below code perfectly worked for me as I moved button click inside paragraph click.

```
function highlight(){
 $(document).on('click', 'p.raw_text', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation()
      var selectedRange = getSelectedText()
        $(document).off('click', '[id^=highlight]')
        $(document).on('click', '[id^=highlight]', function(ev) {
          var text = selectedRange.toString();
          if(!text)return;
            console.log(selectedRange.toString())
            hiliter(text, e.target, $(ev.target).data())
        });
    }); 
}

function hiliter(word, element, data) {
  console.log("data", data.color)
  var rgxp = new RegExp(word, 'g');

  var repl = '<span style="background-color:'+ data.color +';">' + word + '</span>';
  element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(rgxp, repl);
}
```

**P.S**- With my little knowledge of `jquery`, I am not sure if I am doing it right way. Please verify someone. Thank you